# Domain name is added to post request in react

Tags: reactjs, post, dns, cross-domain

So i have a frontend (react, Node.js) and a backend Springboot. Both are uploaded to the same remote hosting service (https://app.jelastic.elastx.net/).

I placed the frontend in one environment and the backend in another. They both work fine separately.

I connected me frontend to my domain and in my domain went into DNS-post (A-post) settings and entered the ip of my frontend.

However when i post to my frontend the domain name is attached to the post that goes to my backend. So instead of getting

Post 10.50.3.204/api/auth/signin

i get POST http://remdent.com/10.50.3.204/api/auth/signin

which ofc come back as 404 (Not Found).

So how do i remove the Domain name from being attached to the post ?
thank you

Comment: did you solve the issue? if yes how, i am getting same issue, and need help.

Answer (score 0):

10.50.3.204 seems to be internal IP (not a public IP) and you should not be using/adding any IP in code/settings. Instead you should be having an entry in /etc/hots file "10.50.3.204  remdent.com" of your front-end host (Assuming 10.50.3.204 is your back-end host's IP address)

Comment: I cant even find the file you speak of the ect/host file. Can you elaborate on where to fin it plz.

Comment: If you are using linux then /etc/hosts is the file but you need to be a sudo user and have permission to edit the file. If it you are using a windows then it will be located at %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: the server is located on https://app.jelastic.elastx.net/ its a remote hosting service where you can place your applications. I have admin there